Unit testing PNG quantization by Sharp in Jest
I am fetching PNG files from a 3rd party API endpoint and quantizing them using Sharp before sending the response to the client. How can I unit test the quantization process?
My intention was to have two tests, one asserting that the quantized image is smaller than the original, and one checking the number of color levels in the quantized image matches the number specified in the Sharp call (256). However, I'm struggling to make it work as intended. Any suggestions welcomed!
